# Hangman game (Python)

Tags: python

I was making a simple Hangman game in Python. 
However, I have some problem in the following piece of code

```
newword=""

def update(word,guessword,ch):
    for i in range(len(guessword)-1):
        if ch==word[i]:
            print(i)
            if i==0:
                newword=ch + guessword[1:]
            else:
                newword=guessword[0:i-1] + ch + guessword[i+1]
    return newword
```

This update function is called when a match is found and is used to update guessword.
Here guessword is a string containing "_" for every unmatched position. The string word hold the original word. ch is the letter which is found in the original word.

Comment: @khelwood we both edit + made the **exact** same changes, at the very same time! LOL

Comment: @OlivierPons I guess we both must know what we're doing then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `range(len(guessword)):`. The `-1` is not needed, `range` already excludes the upper bound.
2. Use `guessword[i+1:]` at the end - you forgot the `:`. Otherwise it's just one character.

That should fix your existing code. To make it better, I suggest making `guessword` a `list` of characters so that you can modify it, then the whole thing will become much simpler. Also use `enumerate` instead of `range`.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it now and it's working. Basic error though!! Thanks for your help

Comment: Also I think it should be `guessword[:i] + ch + guessword[i+1:]`. If you stop the first substring at `i-1` then you omit the character before the one you're trying to replace.

Comment: @khelwood we have to replace the ith index, so how can we do guessword [ :i]?

Comment: @AnantMathur `guessword[:i]` does not include the ith index.

Comment: Oh yes @khelwood